# How to add a file extension to file without any

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I've downloaded a few blank HTML files with no file extensions.

(I know these are HTML because if I manually add .HTML to the end and open the file, / the file contains html elements.... like  etc.)

So they're located in my downloads folder. I'm simply trying to add a file extension to each of these files in the dir folder "download".

Here's my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('C:/Users/Nikki/Downloads').forEach(file => { 
    console.log(file); 

    //There is a file named "desktop.ini", skip this file.
    if (file === "desktop.ini") {
        console.log("desktop file")
    } else {

    //not sure why it doesn't change the file extension. Maybe because there is none!?
    var replaceExt = require('replace-ext');

    var path = 'C:/Users/Nikki/Downloads/' + file;
    var newPath = replaceExt(path, '.html');

    console.log(newPath); 

}

/*
fs.rename(file, file+'.html', () => { 
    console.log("\nFile Renamed!\n"); 

// doesnt work... either...
}); 
*/
});
```

How can I add the HTML file extension to each of these files?

Comment: Why are you requiring a module in the middle of the loop?

Comment: i recommend you to require the modules you gonna use in the beginning of the file, since this way you just make one importation and use it as you need

Comment: It was just a quick test purpose.. to mimic / replace the code below it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file doesn't have a file extension, you can try the following code snippet :

```
var pos = file.lastIndexOf(".");
file = file.substr(0, pos < 0 ? file.length : pos) + ".html";
```

Comment: There would be no last index of "." because there is no file extension.

Comment: So it doesn't contain any periods.

Comment: @Ownslo then it will add the .html at last which is what we need.